# Selenium (Python): Remove all webelements from text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape twitter, and I am concerned only with the tweet text as off now. When I narrow my down to the 'p' tag that contains the text, there are unprecedented tags like 'strong' inside the text that I just can't get rid off.

For example, this is what outputs when I print my tag text:

```
> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
> (session="5dd609e4b0694f9c363007d68d5b698a",
> element="0.02910224956545071-1")>
> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
> (session="5dd609e4b0694f9c363007d68d5b698a",
> element="0.02910224956545071-2")> Trevor Noah challenging Tomi Lahren
> and her stance on Black Lives Matter, her racist narratives, Donald
> Trump and more
```

While the output I expect is as follows:

```
> Trevor Noah challenging Tomi Lahren and her stance on Black Lives
> Matter, her racist narratives, Donald Trump and more
```

Another example is as follows:

```
> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
> (session="5dd609e4b0694f9c363007d68d5b698a",
> element="0.18626949664745118-10")> If the Cubs can win the World
> Series, Donald Trump can win the presidency, and the Cowboys can win
> 11-straight, then I can survive finals
```

Here is what I expect:

```
> If the Cubs can win the World
> Series, Donald Trump can win the presidency, and the Cowboys can win
> 11-straight, then I can survive finals
```

The number of occurrences and position of this webelement is different for every iteration, and hence I'm stuck.
I have tried regex, but couldn't solve the issue. Any help would be appreciated.
Thankyou!

Comment: can you share url ? and code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

[Always read the docs first!](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text)

```
>>> tweet_element = tweet.find_element_by_class_name("js-tweet-text-
container").‌​find_element_by_tag_‌​name("p").text. print(re.sub(r'.*>', 
'', str(id))) 
>>> tweet_element.text
"If the Cubs can win the World Series, Donald Trump can win the >>> 
presidency, and the Cowboys can win 11-straight, then I can survive 
finals"
```

Selenium is not recommended for scraping. Please, if you can, switch to either the [official Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview), [Tweepy](http://www.tweepy.org/) (a Python library for the Twitter API), or even [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#quickstart) and [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: This is what my code to find the text looks like: id = tweet.find_element_by_class_name("js-tweet-text-container").find_element_by_tag_name("p").text.
            print(re.sub(r'.*>', '', str(id)))

Comment: Figured it out using BeautifulSoup, thanks! I couldn't use tweepy because tweepy has a limitation of 7 days of historical data while i'm interested in 5+ years of historical data. I can't use beautifulsoup for scrapping because beutifusoup is meant for static content only. I need to scroll on my webpage in order to get the complete content. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it using beautifulsoup.

```
id = tweet.find_element_by_class_name("js-tweet-text-container").find_element_by_tag_name("p").text
                soup = BeautifulSoup(id)
                text = soup.get_text()
                print(text)
```